# Any tip to use ASCII characters?

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I'm making a program using ASCII characters, but I got an error(CS0019) while declaring the characters. Any solution or tip to fix this

I get the error in this declaration:

```
"if ((c >= 66 && c < 90 || c >= 97) && c <= 122 && c != 65 && c !=73 && c ! =85 && c !=97 && c != 101 && c != 105 && c != 111 && c != 117)"


static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "example.abc123";

            int vowels = 0;
            int consonants = 0;
            int numbers = 0;

            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                if (c >= 48 && c <= 57)
                {
                    numbers++;
                }
                    if (c == 65 || c == 69 || c == 73 || c == 79 || c == 85 || c == 97 || c == 101 || c == 105 || c == 111 || c == 117)
                {
                    vowels++;
                }
                if ((c >= 66 && c < 90 || c >= 97) && c <= 122 && c != 65 && c !=73 && c ! =85 && c !=97 && c != 101 && c != 105 && c != 111 && c != 117)
                {
                    consonants++;
                }
```

Comment: Make sure to tag your question with the programming language you're using so the people who know that language are more likely to see it.

Comment: `c ! =85` ? Are you sure?

Comment: Please edit your question to include details like what line the error is on. Also, what is the string at the top of your current code? Just declaring a string value like that outside of a method should also cause a problem.

Comment: This looks like an exam / course related question. Did you learn about else-expressions yet? They will make your code way more readable and your issue will be way more easy to spot (or even disappear) as less code means less possibilities for errors (in your case) ;)

Comment: @Compufreak You're right, and I totally forgot about else, TY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a space between the `!` and the `=` in one of your `!=` operators. The error will go away if you replace this: `c ! =85` with this: `c != 85`

---

FYI, there is an easier way to check if a character is a vowel. We can use a string to represent all vowels, and then check if it contains the character:

```
public static bool IsVowel(char c)
{
    return "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c);
}
```

We could also do the same thing for consonants, or we could use the `IsLetter` method of the `char` class to determine if the character is a letter, and then reuse our `IsVowel` method above:

```
public static bool IsConsonant(char c)
{
    return char.IsLetter(c) && !IsVowel(c);
}
```

Also, the `char` class has a static `IsDigit` method that will return `true` if a character is a digit.

So, combining these, we could simplify the code to:

```
foreach (char c in text)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(c)) numbers++;
    else if (IsVowel(c)) vowels++;
    else if (IsConsonant(c)) consonants++;
}
```